# Static init of map versus init as part of declaration

Tags: java

Is there an advantage of initialising a map in static block versus initialising it as part of the declaration?

Init as part of declaration :

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> init1 = Map.ofEntries(Map.entry("1" , 1),
                     Map.entry("2" , 2));
```

Init static block :

```
private static final Map<String , Integer> init2 ;

static {
    init2 = Map.ofEntries(Map.entry("1" , 1),
            Map.entry("2" , 2));
}
```

Comment: In this sample case, I don't see that it makes any difference.

Comment: Or how about `Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("1", 1, "2", 2);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static block has only one advantage in case you will have some complex initialization logic, for example, error handling or loop. See [Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

> If initialization requires some logic (for example, error handling or
> a for loop to fill a complex array), simple assignment is inadequate.
> Instance variables can be initialized in constructors, where error
> handling or other logic can be used. To provide the same capability
> for class variables, the Java programming language includes static
> initialization blocks.

In your example, both cases are the same.